# Dynamic Where in SAS - Conditional Operation based on another set

Tags: sas

To my disappointment, the following code, which sums up 'value' by week from 'master' for weeks which appear in 'transaction' does not work -

```
data master;
     input week value;

datalines;
1 10
1 20
1 30
2 40
2 40
2 50
3 15
3 25
3 35
;
run;



data transaction;
     input change_week ;

datalines;
1
3 
;
run;


data _null_;

    set transaction;

    do until(done);
        set master end=done;
        where week=change_week;


        sum = sum(value, sum);
    end;

    file print;
    put week= sum=;

run;
```

SAS complains, rightly, because it doesn't see 'change_week' in master and does not know how to operate on it.

Surely there must be a way of doing some operation on a subset of a master set (of course, suitably indexed), given a transaction dataset... Does any one know?

Comment: I know this is a toy example: is the real example also a 1 variable key combination between the two datasets (ie, here CHANGE_WEEK = WEEK is just one variable)?

Comment: It would be have about 3 keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the closest answer to what the asker has requested.

This method uses an index on `week` on the large dataset, allowing for the possibility of invalid `week` values in the transaction dataset, and without requiring either dataset to be sorted in any particular order. Performance will probably be better if the master dataset is in week order.

For small transaction datasets, this should perform quite a lot better than the other solutions as it only retrieves the required observations from the master dataset. If you're dealing with > ~30% of the records in the master dataset in a single transaction dataset, Quentin's method may sometimes perform better due to the overhead of using the index.

```
data master(index = (week));
input week value;
datalines;
1 10
1 20
1 30
2 40
2 40
2 50
3 15
3 25
3 35
;
run;

data transaction;
input week ;
datalines;
1
3
4
;
run;

data _null_;
    set transaction;
    file print;

    do until(done);
        set master key = week end=done;
        /*Prevent implicit retain from previous row if the key isn't found,
          or we've read past the last record for the current key*/
        if _IORC_ ne 0 then do;
          _ERROR_ = 0;
          call missing(value); 
        end;
        else sum = sum(value, sum);
    end;
    put week= sum=;
run;
```

N.B. for this to work, the indexed variable in the master dataset must have exactly the same name and type as the variable in the transaction dataset. Also, the index must be of the non-unique variety in order to accommodate multiple rows with the same key value.

Also, it is possible to replace the `set master...` statement with an equivalent `modify master...` statement if you want to apply transactional changes directly, i.e. without SAS making a massive temp file and replacing the original.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I didn't know you can directly access elements in this way. I tried switching this to modify but it didn't seem to work.

Does SAS really make a temp file for the example here? My impression is that with data _null_, SAS won't make any temp file.

Comment: You would also need to change `data _null_;` to `data master;` in order to modify the master dataset this way. This is is the only way to avoid creating a temporary file when using a data step to make changes to values stored in a dataset. You are correct that no temp file is created when you're using a `data _null_`.

Comment: When I tried, I did swap the top to master, but it didn't work. I am sure it is some minor problem that I could fix.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, there are many ways to do this in SAS.  Your example is inefficient because (once we got it working) it would still require a full read of "master" for ever line of "transaction".

(The reason you got the error was because you used `where` instead of `if`.  In SAS, the sub-setting `where` in a data step is only aware of columns already existing within the data set it's sub-setting.  They keep two options because there `where` is faster when it's usable.)

An alternative solution would be use `proc sql`.  Hopefully this example is self-explanatory:

```
proc sql;
    select
        a.change_week,
        sum(b.value) as value
    from
        transaction as a,
        master as b
    where a.change_week = b.week
    group by change_week;
quit;
```

Comment: My example is a toy example to illustrate the problem. In reality, I won't be doing 'sum()', but a lot of complicated equations which are not possible within SQL. 

Efficiency is why I want to use 'where' instead of 'if'. You are correct that 'if' would scan the whole set, but so would SQL. The where clause in SQL works AFTER the whole data is scanned.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I think that most SQL engines would be able to do this kind of query without redundant reads.

Comment: proc sql _method _tree; will reveal how SQL makes its decision regarding the process. 'Where" is a clause in SQL and is executed last. You can read about it here http://www.lexjansen.com/wuss/2005/data_warehousing_and_database_management/dwdb_where_the_statement.pdf

Comment: My initial trials indicate that SQL can exploit the index if it the set has been indexed. It's all so obvious as an afterthought

Comment: Index or no, the SQL reads the whole thing once.  Which is different from the first draft of your program, which would read it three times.  Anyway, I'm glad you asked the question because I learned some things from user667489's answer.

Comment: With SQL, the access was much much faster. So it must be something else which speeds it up.

Ha, pleasure to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest below solution (would like @Jeff's SQL solution or even a hash better).  But just for playing with data step logic, I think below approach would work, if you trust that every key in transaction will exist in master.  It relies on the fact that both datasets are sorted, so only makes one pass of each dataset.

On first iteration of the DATA step, it reads the first record from the transaction dataset, then keeps reading through the master dataset until it finds all the matching records for that key, then the DATA step loop iterates and it does it again for the next transaction record.

```
1003  data _null_;
1004      set transaction;
1005      by change_week;
1006
1007      do until(last.week and _found);
1008          set master;
1009          by week;
1010
1011          if week=change_week then do;
1012            sum = sum(value, sum);
1013            _found=1;
1014          end;
1015       end;
1016
1017      *file print;
1018      put week= sum= ;
1019  run;

week=1 sum=60
week=3 sum=75
```

Comment: Yes, this is an alternative, still requiring a whole scan of MASTER, just as the SQL where clause will still scan the whole of MASTER